# Android Manifest displaying Main Menu

Tags: android, android-manifest

Can anyone guide me, Im trying to create a simple app that has splash and main menu activity.

I have implemented both of the activity and whenever I run the emulator I can see the splash pop up but it never goes to the main menu activity.

I tried to change the XML file in manifest as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.book" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".activity.StartApp">
 <activity 
        android:name=".activity.MainMenuApp"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activity.SplashApp" 
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Can anyone suggest why the main menu did not show up?

Thanks.

Edit: SplashApp.java

```
import com.book.R;
public class SplashApp extends Activity {

private DBAdapter mDBAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {

    super.onStart();
    mDBAdapter = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());

    try{

... 
….      int sec = 1;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashApp.this, MainMenuApp.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                finish();
            }
        }, sec * 1000);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I found that the problem might be on my manifest file where it says:

```
package="com.book"
```

I am now able to load the splash activity but it won’t go to the main menu page?

Comment: Could you please share the `SplashApp` activity's code as well? If the "Main menu" as you referred it is also an Activity, it should be also declared in this manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your **main menu activity** is actually an `Activity`, it should be also noted in the `androidManifest.xml` file (with or without intent filters):

```
...
<activity android:name=".activity.MainMenu" 
    android:label="@string/main_menu">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
...
```

In case you are performing initialization tasks in the `SplashApp` activity, and the main functions of your applications reside in the `MainActivity`, you would find the `DEFAULT` intent filter useful though.

**edit1:** remove the `android:name` attribute from the `application` tag in the manifest

**edit2:** use `SplashApp.this.finish()` instead of simply `finish()`, because the **this** there refers to the Handler.

**SplashApp.java:**

```
package com.book.activity;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import com.book.R;

public class SplashApp extends Activity
{
    private DBAdapter mDBAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        mDBAdapter = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        try
        {
            ArrayList<BookBean> books = mDBAdapter.getAllBooks();
            if (books == null)
            {
                InputStream instream = getAssets().open("bookdata.txt");
                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
                String line;
                while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String arr[] = line.split("***");
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
                    {
                        String temp[] = arr[i].split("*");
                        BookBean book = new BookBean();

                        book.setDescription((temp[0]));
                        book.setName(temp[1]);
                        book.setYearPublished(temp[2]);
                        mDBAdapter.insertBook(book);
                    }
                }
            }
            final int sec = 1;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashApp.this, MainMenuApp.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    SplashApp.this.finish();
                }
            }, sec * 1000);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**androidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.book" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".activity.MainMenuApp" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.SplashApp" 
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I have changed the manifest as shown above but I still got a "force close" error.

Comment: The the logcat part would be useful as well; This code above works properly (the layout / lifecycle part), so the problem must be in retrieving the data from the database / populating your list. Please paste the log output of the exception. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure where to find the log output, but on the logcat I saw e.g:

_E/AndroidRuntime(579). Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundExceptino: com.book.activity.activity.StartApp in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader_

Comment: :) well you can (and you **should**) totally avoid the `name` attribute in your `application` tag inside the `androidManifest.xml`. That is used only in case you've overwritten the `Application` class to have one of your own. **android:name** attribute: `An optional name of a class implementing the overall android.app.Application for this package`.

Comment: So you suggesting me to remove the **android:name:**? 

I can run the app and the splash show but as I said it didn’t go to main menu page. And it doesn’t have any error showing on logcat either.

Comment: Thanks, have changed the 
    `finish();` 
to 
    `SplashApp.this.finish();`

in Splash class - still only can view the splash screen but it didn’t go to main menu page.

Comment: you should removethe name attribute. I've just tried, and it works fine for me with dummy data. Let me know if not, and I'll implement the the rest too.

Comment: So you suggest me to remove all these:

**
android:name=”.activity.StartApp”
..
..

android:name=“.activity.MainMenuApp”
..
..

android:name=“.activity.SplashApp”
**

Is that what you mean?

Comment: I have removed all the name attribute as mentioned above; then when I run it loaded to splash screen only - it still did not go to main menu at all.

Comment: No, I meant to remove it only from the application tag: .activity.StartApp. The rest, the two Activity extensions must be in the com.book.activity package.

Comment: Thanks I have removed as you suggested:

http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/2356/75350692.png

but now the app not even run on the emulator? can you please show me what you did...?

Comment: Please see the updates in the answer, I've attached the source files I've modified and used: a layout inflated from SplashApp is showing for 1 second, then the `MainMenuApp` activity starts, and it's layout is displayed. If you still have troubles, probably would be better to take a look at your `MainMenuApp` class: why doesn't it start up?

Comment: I have copy and paste the manifest file into mine - and the result I got the same as before; I can only loaded the splash then it stuck/froze there not going to main menu page. I looked at the main menu app class and it seems all fine. I tested by changing the manifest file so it loaded directly without go to splash screen and it seems work that way. 

Anyway, really not sure what is going on my code drive me mad - but thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd really suggest you to share the `MainMenuApp` class too, and check whether there's anything different in your `SplashApp` activity and the one you've shared. Also, when you're starting to blame the compiler, you probably need a break :)

Comment: Here is my MainMenuApp class - Please ignore the red underline as it gone once I've clean the project. 

Here is the link: 
http://img515.imageshack.us/img515/5701/55688536.png

Please let me know what did I miss...!o_O

Comment: At a first glance everything looks ok. But why do you need a custom `Application` extension? If you want to use it (for some reason...), the application's name attribute should be set to `com.book.activity.StartApp`. Also, could you please change the part: `e.printStackTrace();` into `Log.e('ERROR','Problem fetching data',e);`? This way it will show up in the LogCat output, so we can investigate.